# How to pass string as parameter in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a simple sample of passing `string` parameter in URL not using the `queryString` at this example. First of all I added a new `MapRoute`to `RouteConfig.cs` file as

```
           routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
           routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "app",
                  url: "{controller}/{action}/{name}"
            );
```

and in Controller I have

```
 public class AppController : Controller
    {
        public string Index(string name)
        {
            return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Hello " + name );
        }
    }
```

but the view is not displaying the string parameter. For example a URL like this `http://localhost:59013/App/Index/Ali` only return `Hello`!

[image]

Why is this happening?

### Update

```
  routes.MapRoute(
      name: "app",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{name}",
      defaults: new {action = "Index" }
);
    routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: Change the order of your registered routes. The default has to be the last. **But**, your `app` route pattern is wrong and will always collide with the default route. You better change its pattern to `url: "App/Index/{name}"` (or perhaps to the more friendlier `url: "App/{name}"`) both with `defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Index" }`.

Comment: Thanks Haim770, you were right changing the custom route priority fixed the issue but how can I get rid of the `\index`  in the url? I already add `defaults: new {action = "Index" }` but I am getting error when I try something like `http://localhost:59013/App/Ali/`

Comment: Please add the modified routes to the question

Comment: Can you please check the update?

Comment: See my answer. You're missing the `controller = "App"` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to change the order of your registered routes so the default will be the last.

Secondly, your `app` route pattern is wrong and will always collide with the default route. You better change its pattern to

```
url: "App/Index/{name}"
```

Or perhaps to the more friendlier

```
url: "App/{name}"
```

Both with

```
defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Index" }
```

So that your routes would look like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "app",
    url: "App/{name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

Comment: @MonaCoder, Does your routes look exactly like what in the answer? What's the Url you're trying?

Comment: I am getting `Server Error in '/' Application.` error I modified the defaults but still not able to land to page without the index

Comment: @MonaCoder, What does the error says? And what's the Url?

Comment: I see I fixed it but isn't this a little bit very specific? I mean suppose I have another controller called `MapControoler`, then I have to write same `MapRoute()` for that too? Is there any way to make it more generic?

Comment: @MonaCoder, You already have that "generic" capability through the default route that will let you reach any action using the `{controller}/{action}` pattern. Once you need to reach a specific action using a different parameter name in the last segment (`{name}` instead of `{id}`), the framework must be able to tell them apart, and that would mean a distinctive Url pattern to the more specific one. However, it's worth looking whether there's a solution that is based on the parameter index rather than the name (you can always use the query-string though: `/App/Index?name=...`).